# WCF proxy client generated with wsdl not matching for DataContractSerilizer

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

WCF proxy client generated with wsdl not matching for DataContractSerilizer. My model is [DataContract], but the proxy client generated with XmlSerializerFormat attributes. what's wrong?

Comment: how did you generate the proxy?

Comment: `/ser:XmlSerializer` - **Generates data types that use the XmlSerializer for serialization and deserialization.**

Comment: I add a wcf server reference, auto-generate the file Reference.cs which is proxy client

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh, I do not know that my model is [DataContract], why generate the Reference.cs with XmlSerializer not DataContractSerilizer?